# Python crossover or switch formula

Tags: python, switch-statement

I would like a formula or anything that acts like a "switch". If the column 'position' goes to 3 or above, the switch is turned on (=1). If 'position' goes above 5, the switch is turned off (=0). And if position goes below 3, the switch is also turned off (=0). I have included the column 'desired' to display what I would like this new column to automate.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['position'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
df['desired'] =  [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]
```

Comment: `df['position'].map(lambda x: 3 <= x <= 5)`?

Comment: what with `5,4,3` in `6,5,4,3,2` - shouldn't be `1` ? You have `0`.

Comment: @furas It seems the switch has a state which only changes at the mentioned trigger points.

Comment: You describe this as if you expect it to involve caring about previous results of calculations, but it seems that it doesn't really - you don't care about the position value "going to" a certain range, but only about whether the current value is actually in that range. Yes?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think you should write that up as an answer; I don't see why the solution needs to be any more complicated than that.

Comment: there is only one on switch, to go above 2 ... going above 5 or below 3 shuts it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `.shift()` to create row with shifted `position` to have current and provious value in one row. And then I can check if it goes above 3 or 5 or below 3 and change value which will be assigned to in column `'desired'`.

After creating column `'desired' I have to drop shifted data.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['position'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
#df['desired'] = [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]

df['previous'] = df['position'].shift()

# ---    

value = 0

def change(row):
    global value

    #print(row)
    if (row['previous'] < 3) and (row['position'] >= 3):
        value = 1
    if (row['previous'] >= 3) and (row['position'] < 3):
        value = 0
    if (row['previous'] <= 5) and (row['position'] > 5):
        value = 0

    return value

# ---

#for ind, row in df.iterrows():
#    print(int(row['position']), change(row))

df['desired'] = df.apply(change, axis=1)

df.drop('previous', axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result

```
    position  desired
0          1        0
1          2        0
2          3        1
3          4        1
4          5        1
5          6        0
6          7        0
7          8        0
8          7        0
9          6        0
10         5        0
11         4        0
12         3        0
13         2        0
14         1        0
15         2        0
16         3        1
17         4        1
18         5        1
19         4        1
20         3        1
21         2        0
22         1        0
```